# Does any one know a software like Piwik which is not under GPL license?

Tags: matomo

I need to integrate an offline analytics software to a my software.
My software is not under GPL, its under proprietory license.

Does any one know of a software similar to [Piwik](http://piwik.org/)
but which has relaxed licensing like BSD, MIT etc.

Comment: I would add that fully integrating Piwik into another software project would be a bear as it is, from my perspective, written in a non-standard implementation of Zend Framework. We tried several times to integrate the tracking code using their PHP hooks with our own application, also written in Zend Framework, and it broke the environment royally.  Just use their Javascript embed code and put piwik on a separate subdomain and/or server and you will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't exist. Piwik is in GPL, but you can use it in your commercial project as long as you don't redistribute it. Check out the FAQ: [Can I get the data from the Piwik API web services and publish, reuse, process this data in a non GPL software?](http://piwik.org/faq/new-to-piwik/#faq_56)

Comment: Does that answer your question?